# How to remove Windows 7 Shortcut keys

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I disable some shortcut keys from windows 7?
I'm trying to use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

on eclipse but no success, and:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

makes my screen go upside down instead of copying the lines I've selected..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to control panel and open the graphic controller property dialog by double clicking on the icon of your graphic driver (in my case it was Intel Extreme Graphics).

It may be different in your case.

In that dialog there must be an option to disable/enable the shortcuts.
In my case the shorcuts were called hotkeys.
Removing the checkbox before it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Those shortcuts are probably taken by your video card drivers. Go to the control panel of it and disable the shortcuts.

---

edit: What I'm trying to say is that windows is not taking those keys, it's another application.